# Shopping Cart Integration -- Experiences with Popular eCommerce Solutions

Tags: plugin-recommendation, e-commerce

Researching various shopping cart solutions for a WordPress based eCommerce website. Based on research, it seems that two plugins stand out:

- shopplugin.net
- phpurchase.com

Can anyone share their experiences with these or offer some good alternatives?

The list of requirements is too long to include here, but the store will be shipping goods (not digital products) and the ability to have a robust marketing/promotional campaign integrated into the shopping experience is important, as is financial reporting. Product recommendations, coupons, sale prices/discounts, email marketing and a customer database would all be nice features to have.

I don't like WP-ecommerce or most of the other free options and the budget for software is as much as $1,000 (alternatively looking at shopify.com, a non-WP product). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WooCommerce all the way: http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/

Answer (score 2):

I find DukaPress to be very easy to use for my clients and its packed with features that answer to most of your requirements.
And its free so you can't bet that.
Check it out http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dukapress/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, are there any limitations to Dukapress that you have experienced or that stand out?

Comment: My bigest problem with dukapress was developing a custom payment gateway but i can't really think of limitations that you can't get around by bits of custom coding

Answer (score 1):

We have used [Fleapay Shopping Cart](http://www.fleapay.com) for a bunch of our sites. It's great to implement for a customer who's needs are pretty basic, but includes tax and shipping.

It's extremely quick and easy to plugin. It's best suited for clients using a merchant/gateway and emulates the PayPal "Buy It Now" buttons, however, you can customize it locally with CSS. That in itself makes it a much better offering than PayPal Standard.

Answer (score 0):

I have one more suggestion, try this [premium X-Cart](http://mods.x-cart.com/WordPress-in-X-Cart) integrated with wordpress
I have not used it, but one of my friend told me, also have look at that

Answer (score -1):

We've used Shopp, WP-eCommerce, ZenCart, osCommerce, and some other not-so-popular cart software.

Based on our experiences - as a professional software developers - we find that WooCommerce is the best available so far for small and medium sized stores. The code is well organized, easy to read and follow, and there is steady development on the code base by the developers. Which is what led to the creation of IgniteWoo.com, we like it so much we stopped developing code for other cart software and now focus entirely on WooCommerce ;-)

Comment: And what is the exact value of this answer, aside from a link to your site?